# How to explode an array without duplicate records

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark-sql, databricks, pyspark

This is continuation to the question here in [pyspark sql Add different Qtr start_date, End_date for exploded rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344243/pyspark-sql-add-different-qtr-start-date-end-date-for-exploded-rows/62346339?noredirect=1#comment110265832_62346339).  Thanks.

I have the following dataframe which has a array list as a column.

```
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------+-----------+----------+
customer_number|sales_target|start_date|end_date  |noq|cf_values|new_sdt    |new_edate |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|2020-10-01 |2020-12-31|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------------------+----------+
```

I need to have a column with one cf_values for each row, added withcolumn to existing record.  If i use the explode, am getting dupicate records, so end up getting 16 records.

```
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------+------+-----------+----------+
customer_number|sales_target|start_date|end_date  |noq|cf_values|cf_new|new_sdt    |new_edate |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------+------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-01-01 |2019-12-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|3     |2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-04-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|3     |2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-07-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|3     |2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|4     |2020-10-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |[4,4,4,3]|3     |2020-10-01 |2020-12-30|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+---------+------------------+----------+
```

Expected result:
4 records with 4 different cf_values, new start_date new_end_date.

```
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------+-----------+----------+
customer_number|sales_target|start_date|end_date  |noq|cf_new|new_sdt    |new_edate |
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------------------+----------+
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |4     |2020-01-01 |2020-03-31|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |4     |2020-04-01 |2020-06-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |4     |2020-07-01 |2020-09-30|
|A011021       |15          |2020-01-01|2020-12-31|4  |3     |2020-10-01 |2020-12-31|
+--------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------------------+----------+
```

Comment: what is the condition of filtering a single value from the array?

Comment: Not sure if i understood your question correctly, but for a given a customer number, based on the start date & end date column value, I have created seperate rows using sequence & explode functions.  The cf_new array length would be equal to number of rows/quarters for a given customer number.  Each array element should be inserted in each row, as per the order of the array.  Thanks. There is a link is in the beginning, you can refer for more info please.

Comment: [Please, See Answer mvasyliv. Two DataFrame and then Join ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62344243/pyspark-sql-add-different-qtr-start-date-end-date-for-exploded-rows/62346663#62346663)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of exploding the array, you can pick the values from the array based on it's position.

This position can be dynamically generated using `row_number` as shown below.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number, expr
from pyspark.sql import Window

window = Window.partitionBy('customer_number').orderBy('new_sdt')

df.withColumn('row_num', row_number().over(window)).\
withColumn('cf_new', expr("cf_values[row_num - 1]")).\
drop('row_num').show()
```

Output:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------------+----------+----------+------+
|customer_number|sales_target|start_date|  end_date|noq|   cf_values|   new_sdt| new_edate|cf_new|
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------------+----------+----------+------+
|        A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|  4|[4, 4, 4, 3]|2020-01-01|2020-03-31|     4|
|        A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|  4|[4, 4, 4, 3]|2020-04-01|2020-06-30|     4|
|        A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|  4|[4, 4, 4, 3]|2020-07-01|2020-09-30|     4|
|        A011021|          15|2020-01-01|2020-12-31|  4|[4, 4, 4, 3]|2020-10-01|2020-12-31|     3|
+---------------+------------+----------+----------+---+------------+----------+----------+------+
```